# How does eclipse provide Override/implement methods widget?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Which class of eclipse  displays a frame which  called  override/implement methods, when we right click-->source-->override methods

Comment: What do you mean by "does come over"?

Comment: how does eclipse pprovide that rightclick-->source-->override methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know but maybe PDE Plug-in Spy can tell you: http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/

**[EDIT]** Here is what I did:

1. I looked for the string "O&verride/Implement Methods..." in the Eclipse sources. It can be found here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/plugin.properties
2. That gave me the property to search for: `OverrideMethodsAction.label` It can be found in the file [`plugin.xml`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/plugin.xml):

   ```
    <action
          definitionId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.override.methods"
          label="%OverrideMethodsAction.label"
          retarget="true"
          menubarPath="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu/generateGroup"
          id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OverrideMethods">
    </action>
   ```
3. The id is the class name.

You can find the source here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/actions/OverrideMethodsAction.java

Comment: Hi I have checked the Spy, actually the idea is explicitly, what i needed that

Comment: Hi thanks for idea, The idea is i need a tool which will display the  information (the code of the widget.) about the widget under the cursor.And spy just provides info about SWT components like this;

Shell {Override/Implement Methods}@1180724
 Style: RESIZE | TITLE | CLOSE | MAX | BORDER | APPLICATION_MODAL | LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
 Layout Data: null
 Bounds: Rectangle {162, 254, 527, 464}


Children:
 Composite {}

Peers:
 CBanner {}@263542 Layout Data: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WindowTrimProxy@15e5b60 Bounds: Rectangle {2, 2, 1678, 29}
 StatusLine {}@459374 Layout Data: org......